# .Net Connection and read to a .DBF file type Visual dBase level 7 format with C#

Tags: c#, dbf, dbase

I cannot to connect to a DBF file type **Visual dBase level 7 format** with C#.

I can read a DBF file type dBase III and dBase IV but with the file type DBF Visual dBase 7 Visual studio return an error message:

"the format table is not on right format expected".

Here is the follow codes I use for an console application:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string filepath = @"C:\Users\user\Desktop\BGF\DATA\";

    OdbcConnection CC = 
    new OdbcConnection("Driver={Microsoft dBase Driver     
    (*.dbf)};SourceType=DBF;SourceDB=" + filepath + ";Exclusive=No; 
    Collate=Machine;NULL=NO;DELETED=NO;BACKGROUNDFETCH=NO;");

    CC.Open();

    OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("Select * From MyDBF_file", CC);
    OdbcDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (dr.HasRows)
    {
         DataTable dt = new DataTable();
         dt.Load(dr);
    }
    CC.Close();

    `enter code here`Console.WriteLine("Successful");
    Console.Read();
}
```

I think the provider is not compatible, but I have tried with Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 does not work. 
And with vfpoledb provider same problem.

I have tried with simple query as 
  OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("Select * From MyDBF_file", CC);

And same problem :-(

Thx in advance for your help or for all approach contribute to a part of solution ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be correct on the CONNECTION.  That should be to the PATH where the tables are located.  However, you QUERY should

```
select * from SomeTableWithinThatPath
```

You are trying to query the PATH, not a specific table.

Comment: With the same code I can connect and read to other type of DBF file as dBase III and dBase IV.

Answer (score 0):

For Visual dBase level 7 format this connections will not work.
You can use code library of dBase IV reader and modify headers to work with Dbase 7 files.

You can find Dbase 7 header information from here.

http://www.dbase.com/KnowledgeBase/int/db7_file_fmt.htm

And DBF reader for older version from here.

https://github.com/eXavera/NDbfReader